# To get a background color only on text inside header element

Tags: background

this is my html structure.

```
<h2>The heading text</h2>.
```

No I need to give background color to the text only. and another background for the space apart from text.

Can i achieve this using pure css and not adding any extra element inside it. [i need the output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raK0Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<h2> black text <span style="background-color: #333;  color: #ccc; "> grey text with dark background </span> another black text</h2>
```

You can style a span within a heading tag or paragraph tag

Comment: Thank u.. but.. I am not supposed to add the additional element into it.. in the model image which i have given the text fill with background-color white and apart from the heading its background image(that diagnol line). but actually i cheive this what u have said.. but now i am not supposed to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<h2>My text <span style="background-color:  #333; ">your text</span> another text </h2>
```

This will give that particular text the desired style including background color

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<h2><span style='color:green'>The</span> <span style='color:blue'>heading</span> 
<span style='color:red'>text</span></h2>.
```